# Card.io java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, card.io

Sometimes after the card is captured the app will crash.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Bitmap.java)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:924)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:901)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:868)
       at io.card.payment.ah.a()
       at io.card.payment.CardIOActivity.a()
       at io.card.payment.CardScanner.onPreviewFrame()
       at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1016)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

It happens every time i capture on the Galaxy S5.
Here are the parameters which I'm using to start scan intent:

```
Intent scanIntent = new Intent(CardInfoActivity.this, CardIOActivity.class);
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_APP_TOKEN, Constants.CARD_IO_TOKEN);
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, true);
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true);
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_CONFIRMATION, true);
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, true);
startActivityForResult(scanIntent, MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Maybe anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: are you using bitmaps?

Comment: I just starting the scan intent and getting result with card number from it. Bitmaps are used inside the lib.

Comment: The problem is that your app is using too much memory. The crash is happening in the card capture because that's where you have a memory spike (especially on the S5 that ha a high resolution). Try running the mat tool and check where your memory is going

Answer (score 0):

Android bitmaps keep the image in native memory, not on the Java heap. If you allocate a bunch of images quickly this can happen, since cleanup only happens when the Java GC runs, which is tied to the Java heap. Ensuring you call `bitmap.recycle()` when you're done with images you've been working with can help.